# ¿Cómo puedo corregir mi código para que me de una lista plegable y formula conectando a mi base datos?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, formularios

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un sistema de inventario, pero en mis formularios que tengo, quiero incluir varias **listas plegables** y adicional quiero que en la **casilla de p_venta** me arroje solo el resultado.

**base de datos (verificar.php):**

```
      <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Base_datos');
    
    /* comprobar la conexión */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM genero");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_genero'] . '">' . $valores['genero'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_categoria'] . '">' . $valores['categoria'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM colores");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_color'] . '">' . $valores['color'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM marcas");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_marca'] . '">' . $valores['marca'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM medidas");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_medida'] . '">' . $valores['medidas'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tallas");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_talla'] . '">' . $valores['talla'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipo");
    echo '<select>';
    while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_tipo'] . '">' . $valores['tipo'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
```

**Archivo .php (registrar.php):**

```
   <?php
  include 'verificar.php';
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_genero * genero FROM genero");
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_marca * marca FROM marcas");
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_categoria * categoria FROM categoria");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_color * color FROM colores");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_medida * medidas FROM medidas");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_talla * talla FROM tallas");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_tipo * tipo FROM tipo");
?>

<html>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Formulario Registrar Producto</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pages/css/registrar.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pin.it/3urbp4j">  
    </head>
 <body>
    </form>
      <selection class="form-register">
        <form style="text-align: center; ">
        <h4>Registar nuevo producto</h4>
        <form action="registrar.php" method="POST">
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="fecha"
            id="fecha"
            placeholder="Fecha"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="id"
            id="id"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Id"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="clave"
            id="clave"
            placeholder="Clave"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="nombre_producto"
            id="nombre_producto"
            placeholder="Nombre del Producto"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="descripcion"
            id="descripcion"
            placeholder="Descripcion"
            required
          />
          <select name="genero" class="controls">
            <?php 
                while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo '<option value="' . $valores['id'] . '">' . $valores['genero'] . '</option>';
                  }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="marca" required>
            <?php
             while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_marca'] . '">' . $valores['marca'] . '</option>';  
               }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="categoria" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_categoria'] . '">' . $valores['categoria'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="tipo" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_tipo'] . '">' . $valores['tipo'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="talla" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_talla'] . '">' . $valores['talla'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="medidas" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_medida'] . '">' . $valores['medidas'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <select class="controls" name="color" required>
            <?php
            while($valores=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="' . $valores['id_color'] . '">' . $valores['color'] . '</option>'; 
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="unidades"
            id="unidades"
            placeholder="Unidades"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="p_compra"
            id="p_compra"
            placeholder="P_Compra"
            required
          />
          <input
            class="controls"
            type="text"
            name="p_venta"
            id="p_venta"
            placeholder="P_Venta"
            required
            <?php 
            $p_compra = 'p_compra';
            $a = '1';
            $b = '70%';

            $resultado = ($p_compra / $a) * $b + $p_compra;
            ?>
          />
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Registrar"/>
        </form>
        </form>
      </selection>
    </body>
  </html>
</html>
```

En el  es la parte del código que debería de traerme todas las opciones que tengo en esa tabla, pero no las trae.

Ya eh modificado de diversas formas el código, pero hay algo que no detecto que está mal.

Utilizo visual studio code para desarrollar mi proyecto, eh descargado varias extensiones para que me sean de utilidad.

¿Podrían auxiliarme?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen que muestro, ya es con los cambios que realice, gracias a **masterguro** pero aun no me pasa las listas desplegable ese es en el .php y abajo en el .html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como ya mencionan es un poco confuso tu pregunta. Si lo que intentas hacer es insertar el bucle ```while``` de **PHP** en un archivo con extensión *.html*, esto no va funcionar, lo fácil cambia tu extensión *.html* por  *.php* y con htaccess podrías cambiarlo por *.html* o sin extensión si lo deseas.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! html se del lado del cliente.. php del lado del servidor...ç

Comment: A ver, de nuevo varias cosas: 1) Lo que tu ves en la "vista previa" de registrar.html es lo que siempre verás en un HTML, porque como ya se te dijo en los comentarios, el HTML **no interpreta el php**, solo HTML.  2) Intenta abrir el registrar.php en un navegador, y 3)No estás aplicando los cambios como te he explicado, sigues usando el **mysql_fecth_array** cuando te he dicho que mejor que uses la sintaxis por objetos, pues así haces la conexión, es decir, lo que ves en mi respuesta, es decir, `$generos->fetch_array()` etc y asegurate que el nombre de las variables coincide en singular/plural

Comment: No uso visual studio code, pero para que veas bien un archivo PHP que usa base de datos debe existir un servidor web (apache por ejemplo) y un servidor de base de datos (mysql) y un interprete de PHP (mejor a partir de la versión 7) **instalados** en algun servidor o bien de forma local en tu PC.  Si no dispones de eso **jamas** te funcionará nada de lo que estas intentando aqui. Y si dispones de ello pon los archivos allí y abrelos con el navegador, no con la vista previa del visual studio code.

Answer (score 1):

En los comentarios has puesto lo siguiente:

```php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'base_datos');
$query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM genero");
while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
  echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'">'.$valores[genero].'</option>'; 
}
?>
```

Lo cual tiene varios errores, a saber:

1. **Verifica** siempre si la conexión a la base de datos es correcta mediante algun tipo de filtro. El que apuntan en el [ejemplo del manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples) es este:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

aunque se podria hacer de otras formas, pero de momento usa este para asegurarte que este paso es correcto.

2. Tal como ves en ese propio ejemplo, **hay dos estilos** para usar funciones `mysqli`, y al hacer esto:

```php
$query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM genero");
```

estas eligiendo el **estilo orientado a *objetos***. Por lo tanto, la siguiente línea está mal, pues corresponde al otro **estilo orientado a *procedimientos***:

```php
while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

y debes sustituirla por esta, con el uso de la misma función pero orientada a objetos, tal como es tu variable `$query`, que se escribe [fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```php
while ($valores = $query->fetch_array()) {
```

3. La siguiente línea, independientemente de si con tu código conseguias entrar o no en el bucle *while* tambien contiene errores:

```
echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'">'.$valores[genero].'</option>';
```

pues **las claves deben entrecomillarse** (con apóstrofes o comillas dobles), por lo tanto debe ser así:

```
echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['genero'].'</option>';
```

Con todos esos cambios, y si la consulta SQL es correcta y devuelve valores de la tabla `genero`, conseguirás generar la salida de los `<option>`, pero al no estar envueltos en un `<select></select>` seguramente te aparecerán como si fuera una lista de lineas. Por lo tanto **debes agregar el principio** del *select* antes de iniciar el bucle, **y el cierre** del *select* justo después del bucle.

Esto seria con todos los cambios completos:

**verificar.php** (quita todos los **selects** de aquí, no pintan nada en este nuevo contexto que has planteado en la actualización de tu pregunta)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'base_datos');

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Y luego en el **registrar.php** debes sustituir todo esto:

```
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_genero * genero FROM genero");
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_marca * marca FROM marcas");
  $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_categoria * categoria FROM categoria");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_color * color FROM colores");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_medida * medidas FROM medidas");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_talla * talla FROM tallas");
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_tipo * tipo FROM tipo");
```

por esto, para diferenciar las consultas, sino estas sobreescribiendo todo el rato la misma variable:

```
$generos = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_genero * genero FROM genero");
$marcas = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_marca * marca FROM marcas");
$categorias = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_categoria * categoria FROM categoria");
$colores = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_color * color FROM colores");
$medidas = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_medida * medidas FROM medidas");
$tallas = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_talla * talla FROM tallas");
$tipos = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_tipo * tipo FROM tipo");
```

y más adelante, en consecuencia, debes ir cambiando los selects de este modo (solo te pongo uno, el resto lo puedes deducir con lo realizado en el cambio anterior):

```
<select name="genero" class="controls">
    <?php 
        while($valores = $generos->fetch_array()) {
            echo '<option value="' . $valores['id'] . '">' . $valores['genero'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Prueba y nos cuentas si lo has conseguido esta vez, o te aparece algun error inesperado.

Comment: Ya borre todos lo comentarios y pude anexar la imagen, de como me arroja en el formulario.